# How can I sort a merged array using usort?

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I have a problem with the ordering of an array.

I use two queries to extract data from two different tables in a MySQL database, then join the results in a single array using `array_merge`. Everything works properly except for a sorting problem. The two tables have a date field in this format `5/25/2015`, and I am trying to sort the extracted data in descending order by this date, but that does not happen.

Here is the code I use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE data between '$one_parameter' and '$second_parameter' and id_ute = '$ute'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $rows;
} 

$sql2 =  "SELECT * FROM tab2 WHERE data_ass between '$one_parameter' and '$second_parameter' and id_ute = '$ute'";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$data2 = array();
while ($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data2[] = $rows2;
}

$combinedData = array_merge($data,$data2);

function cmp($a, $b){           
    return $b['data'] - $a['data_ass'];       
}

usort($combinedData, "cmp");

$json = json_encode($combinedData);
echo $json;
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I need to create something like this, in chronological order:

```
[
    {
        "id_tur": "1886",
        "id_ute": "1",
        "data": "2015-05-22",
        "orario": "13.00 - 19.00",
        "tipo_serv": "home",
    },
    {
        "id_tur": "1877",
        "id_ute": "1",
        "data": "2015-05-12",
        "orario": "00.00 - 09.00",
        "tipo_serv": "work",
    },
    {
        "id_ass": "256",
        "id_ute": "1",
        "data_ass": "2015-05-08",
        "notes": "lorem",
        "tipo_serv": "0",
    },
    {
        "id_turno": "1296",
        "id_ute": "1",
        "data": "2015-05-02",
        "orario": "07.00 - 14.00",
        "tipo_serv": "city",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usort compare same property of different array items

change your second query to:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, data_ass AS data FROM tab2 WHERE data_ass between '$one_parameter' and '$second_parameter' and id_ute = '$ute'";
```

And compare function to:

```
function cmp($a, $b){           
    return $b['data'] > $a['data'];       
}
```